# Android app doesn't launch the main activity and says app isnt installed

Tags: android, android-intent

So im kinda new to android programming and i dont really know why i cant run the main activity when i have a permission tag under the activity. this is my code under the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.lab08b_awahla"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.DANGEROUS_ACTION" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.DANGEROUS_ACTION"
    android:label="permission"
    android:protectionLevel="dangerous" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.lab08b_awahla.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:permission="com.example.DANGEROUS_ACTION" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.DANGEROUS_ACTION" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Does your app compile?

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: it just says that app isnt installed on my device. my main activity isn't being launched because of the permission i have under activity. when i remove the permission it launches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs for the `<activity>` tag](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

> android:permission
>   The name of a permission that clients must have to launch the activity or otherwise get it to respond to an intent. If a caller of startActivity() or startActivityForResult() has not been granted the specified permission, its intent will not be delivered to the activity.

This leads me to think that you misunderstand the use of this attribute.

Comment: yeah i understand that. but if im providing the android permission for the activity shouldn't it still launch the main activity? that is when im trying to launch it from another activity in another application

Comment: The <uses-permission> tag in your manifest has nothing to do with the `android:permission` attribute of your `<activity>`. As the quote above states, the activity which launches your activity must have the permission which you declare in `android:permission`. The standard launcher does *not* have the "com.example.DANGEROUS_ACTION" activity, so as stated, the intent to start your activity will not be delivered to your activity from the launcher.

Comment: is there a way i can fix that? like giving the launcher in my main activity that permission?  or is that impossible? but now i understand what your saying

Comment: @user2255598 You can replace the default launcher with one that has the permission you require for anyone to run your app. That basically means writing a custom launcher app yourself. I doubt this is what you want, though. What exactly do you intend to do?

Comment: so i made 2 apps and i wanted to run the activity of one app from the activity of the other app. i can do that by passing a intent from the first app to start the second app. we were required to have a permission tag in activity to do that and which works. but the only situation it doesnt work is when i try running the second app activity(which is the one im talking about). i know it doenst run because of the permission that i set but i was just wondering is there a way to still run the main activity of the second app on its on rather then running it from another app.

Comment: @user2255598 Please edit your question or post a new one with the contents of the previous comment. This is an entirely different issue than you asked in your original question on this page. I already have some idea of how to do what you want. I think it would be better as an true SO answer, though, rather than a comment.

Comment: @user2255598 Feel free to ping me here with a link to your new question

Comment: code guru i made a new post. Can you please take a look at it? thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15869084/android-app-activity-launches-when-launching-from-another-app-activity-but-doesn

Answer (score 3):

This is obvious. If you are providing a security tag for activity anyone who wants to launch this activity has to have such privilege. Home screen app doesn't have (even don't known) your permission tag so this is a problem.

Comment: i mean i have the android:permission="com.example.DANGEROUS_ACTION" under the activity tag. im able to launch it form another app providing the permission but it doesn't launch the main activity on this app. is there a way to fix it?