# Android app activity launches when launching from another app activity but doesn't launch on its on.

Tags: android, android-intent

so i made 2 apps and i wanted to run the activity of one app from the activity of the other app. i can do that by passing a intent from the first app to start the second app. we were required to have a permission tag in activity to do that and which works. but the only situation it doesnt work is when i try running the second app activity(which is the one im talking about). i know it doenst run because of the permission that i set but i was just wondering is there a way to still run the main activity of the second app on its on rather then running it from another app.

first app manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.lab08a_awahla"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.DANGEROUS_ACTION" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.DANGEROUS_ACTION"
    android:label="perimission"
    android:protectionLevel="dangerous" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.lab08a_awahla.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

first app java code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void clicking(View view){
    Intent i=new Intent();
    i.setAction("com.example.DANGEROUS_ACTION");
    startActivity(i);
}
}
```

second app manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.lab08b_awahla"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.DANGEROUS_ACTION" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.DANGEROUS_ACTION"
    android:label="perimission"
    android:protectionLevel="dangerous" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.lab08b_awahla.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:permission="com.example.DANGEROUS_ACTION" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.DANGEROUS_ACTION" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

so i can launch the activity from the first application activity but second application activity doesn't launch on its on. i thinks its because of the permission tag under activity. when i install it on my device it says "app is not installed". if someone can help me with it i would really appreciate it. thanks

Comment: Do you really need to run the second activity from the Launcher?

Comment: they changed the specs now but i would like to know if i can. just for my personal knowledge? if its too hard then its fine..

Comment: I don't think you can use the android:permission tag if you want your activity to run from both the launcher and from your other activity.

Comment: yeah :(. butt thanks alot for the help :) i really appreciate it

Comment: You can also create an `<alias>` with the `launcher` `intent-filter` in your manifest and point to your `MainActivity`. This way the other apps will need to use the permission and it would still be available to be launched from the app drawer. I have not tested this, but you might want to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you get rid of the `android:permission="com.example.DANGEROUS_ACTION"` from the second app's main activity, you can't launch the app on its own. Because as per your manifest file, home screen app need to have `android:permission="com.example.DANGEROUS_ACTION"` permission to launch the app which is false in your case.